# python counts contributions of categories from csv

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to deduce the volume contributions of each category (like summarize by row value in excel's pivot table) from a csv file (which has two cols ['customer','category']) in to a dict in the following format,

```
foodict = {
   'customer' : 'cust1' , 
   'categories' : { 'cat1' : 50, 'cat2' : 55 } , 
   'contribution' : { 
                     'cat1' : cat1/(cat1+cat2) ,
                     'cat2' : cat2/(cat1+cat2) 
                    }
       }
```

so far, I've got like this, but unable to achieve the needful one. I'm trying to do it in pure python without using any other data libraries.

```
c = {}

for i in customer:
    for j in category:
        for k in db:
           count = 0
           if k['customer'] == i and k['category'] == j:
               count += 1
               if not i in c.keys():
                   c[i] = {'category' : j , 'counts' : count}
               else:
                   pass
```

Comment: You have a number of undefined variables in your code (such as `agents`) that make your example not viable.

Comment: @DYZ corrected now. easier explanation would be like summarize by row value in excel's pivot table

Comment: Please supply more code, there are many referred variables unknown to us. The code sample seems to be wrong as well (`categories` and `contribution(%)` aren't string-value keys?). Also supply the desired output format.

Comment: @LennartKloppenburg the above code block is the desired format, forgive me if my code is incomplete, I am unable to move past that code with my idea. categories & contributions are just custom strings used for the dict as keys. the input file has only two columns.

Comment: @Thuruv It would also help if you could add a few lines from the csv.

Comment: ['customer','Category']
['Cust1','Category 1'],['Cust3','Category 2'],['Cust1','Category 3'],['Cust2','Category 4']

Answer (score 0):

@len:

### *This satisfied my requirement, but is there any efficient way to group by get the count contributions like we do in the excel as 'Summarize by row values in the pivot table*

```
foo_dict = {}
for name in cust:
    for j in category:
        foo_dict[name] = {
                    'total' : int(sum(1 for i in db if i['cust'] == name)),
                    'lob' : {pro : int(sum(1 for i in db if i['cust'] == name and i['category'] == pro)) for pro in category},
                    'conts' : {pro : round(
                        float(
                            sum(1 for i in db if i['cust'] == name and i['category'] == pro)/int(sum(1 for i in db if i['cust'] == name))),2) for pro in category},
                    'samples' : {pro : round(
                        float(
                            sum(1 for i in db if i['cust'] == name and i['category'] == pro)/int(sum(1 for i in db if i['cust'] == name))),0) for pro in category}
                  }
```